# Azure Devops folder structure in azure-pipelines.yml

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In AzureDevops, the pipelines can be viewed as a folder structure.

Is there a way to define this folder structure within each azure-pipelines.yml file? (by specifying a folder location)

If I move a pipeline to a different directory in AzureDevops, how does it still correlate it to an azure-pipelines.yml file in source code?

Comment: Are you talking about the yaml build pipeline or the new yaml multi-stage pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way of doing that. You define path to your yaml file when you create the build, so if you move the yaml file (it doesn't have to be called that exactly) your build will stop working and you will have to update it for it to work.